# How to use response from sim900 module?

Tags: arduino, sms, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sim900

Thanks in advance. I am using arduino and sim900 module to send my sensor data by SMS.

Now I want to check SMS left in my sim card. I'm using below code to do that.`("AT+CUSD=1,\"*451#\"\r")`.

I want to send that response to my mobile. but i don't know how to do that. Any one please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the response from the modem into a string and send it as an SMS.

Comment: Thanks Andii. I added my code below. could you please check that.